# Exception: MissingSchema with Gradio Library

Tags: python, machine-learning, gradio

I'm using the `gradio` library with one of the basic examples, but am getting this error. I am running this in a Google Colab Notebook. Here is the relevant lines of code:

```
fare = gr.inputs.Slider(minimum=0, maximum=1000, default=100, label="Fare (british pounds)")
gr.Interface(predict_survival, [sex, age, fare], "label", live=True).launch();
```

The error is:

```
MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'None': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://None?
```

Answer (score 0):

This error happens with older versions of Gradio. Please force upgrade to the latest version of `Gradio` (sometimes colab doesn't do this automatically):

`pip install gradio --upgrade`